# Why have somebody used this two-outlet heat trap nipple?

Tags: water-heater

I want to replace this t-shaped heat trap nipple because the duct-taped end of it is leaking.

The problem is that maybe there's some not apparent purpose for the open end of the heat trap nipple? (I don't know the person who installed, so...) Like, could it be needed to let out excess presure or something? I am asking because I don't want to make a broken-water-heater problem out of this.
[image: T-shaped heat trap nipple front view]
[image: T-shaped heat trap nipple back view]

Comment: Not sure why that tee would be on there.  Either just a plain connection or a drain, maybe some type of valve.  Tape used like that should only be for a temporary repair/cover.  Replacement of another type/design(with or without the tee) should not cause any trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably set up for a flush valve - fairly common on certain types of water heater to allow acid flushing the heat exchanger to remove mineral deposits.

Duct tape is obviously not the way to stop it, but since you don't show it without the tape on it, it's hard to say what sort of connection to a flush valve is there.

Anyway, putting a flush valve or just a cap on it should solve the leak.